# How to set margin to popup menu in android?

Tags: android

I have a popup menu at the top right corner of the screen. I want to put some margin to its right. How to do that? I couldn't find any solution for this.Every where its done with Popup Window. But I want it with Popup Menu. Please help.Suggestions with proper codes with be very helpful.

I want to put some margin to the right of this popup menu
[image: I want to put some margin to the right of this popup menu]

Comment: Can you provide an image of your desired screen?

Comment: @DroidAks I have added my desired screen. please check.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">-4dp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">4dp</item>
</style>
```

Apply above style in code like below

```
   PopupMenu popup = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            popup = new PopupMenu(context, anchorView, Gravity.END, 0, R.style.MyPopupMenu);
        }else{
            popup = new PopupMenu(context, anchorView);
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
try {
    Field fListPopup = menuHelper.getClass().getDeclaredField("mPopup");
    fListPopup.setAccessible(true);
    Object listPopup = fListPopup.get(menuHelper);
    argTypes = new Class[] { int.class };
    Class listPopupClass = listPopup.getClass();

    // Get the width of the popup window
    int width = (Integer) listPopupClass.getDeclaredMethod("getWidth").invoke(listPopup);

    // Invoke setHorizontalOffset() with the negative width to move left by that distance
    listPopupClass.getDeclaredMethod("setHorizontalOffset", argTypes).invoke(listPopup, -width);

    // Invoke show() to update the window's position
    listPopupClass.getDeclaredMethod("show").invoke(listPopup);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Again, an exception here indicates a programming error rather than an exceptional condition
    // at runtime
    Log.w(TAG, "Unable to force offset", e);
}
```

Comment: Please explain your solution!

Comment: Reflection should be treated as a hacky workaround, not a solution. There should be a proper way to do it, especially that the Material Design [page](https://material.io/guidelines/components/menus.html#menus-simple-menus) suggests that popups should have margins...